# Recent favorites folders in Firefox shows only the last one in dropdown menu

Tags: macos, firefox, favorites

The Favorites dropdown menu in Firefox only shows the last Folder/Location I used.

This is going on since Firefox crashed and I replaced the 'Profile' folder in the Firefox directory with an older version of a few days before.

I would like to see a list of the 15 (I changed the value from 7 to 15) last used folders again.
How can I solve this?

macOS Catalina 10.15.7 (19H2026)
Firefox 102.5 ESR